# Feature Administrator in SharePoint 2010, Exam 70 - 667

Tags: 2010, administration, central-administration, 70-667

I came across this question which seems very confusing to me while preparing for 70 - 667 exam,

> You configure a SharePoint Server 2010 Service Pack 1(SP1) Farm.
>
> You need to ensure that a user named User1 is able to manage only the
> features within an application.
>
> What should you do?
>
> 1. Add User1 as a feature administrator within the particular site collections that require management by non-farm administrators.
> 2. Configure User1 within the Secure Store Server as an administrator.

Now one source says its number 1 and another source says answer is number 2, Can someone guide me which one is right answer and why please.

I did a bit research but couldn't find a lot other then [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263291%28v=office.14%29.aspx) regarding feature administrators.

> Feature administrators   A feature administrator is associated with a
> specific feature or features of a service application. These
> administrators can manage a subset of service application settings,
> but not the entire service application. For example, a Feature
> administrator might manage the Audiences feature of the User Profile
> service application.

On my development machine I am not able to find any settings to assign a user "feature administrator"

**Edit**

All of choices are,

> A. Add User1 as a Feature Administrator within the particular site
> collections that require management by non-farm administrators
>
> B. Make User1 as a site collection administrator of the site collection
> that uses the search scope
>
> C. Separate the service applications
> throughout the farm
>
> D. Add a new Active Directory group to Secure
> Store Service
>
> E. Add a service application administrator at the
> specific service level
>
> F. Configure User1 within the Secure Store
> Server as an administrator
>
> G. Grant contributor permissions to User1
> at the policy level
>
> H. Deploy multiple instances of the same service
> in a farm and assign unique names to the resulting service
> applications
>
> I. Add User1 explicity as a Search administrator within
> the farm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about Managing Site/Site collection Features then it has to be site collection administrator to use site collection features. Option A seems to be correct.

Comment: I think they are talking about service applications as "feature administrator" only exists for service applications according to MSDN article I mentioned, but I can't seem to find "feature administrator" any where within sharepoint 2010 environment:(

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the answer **A** is correct since a feature administrator does just that, and nothing else.

> Farm administrators can delegate administration of either a User Profile service application or selected features of a User Profile service application to a service application administrator. A service application administrator can delegate administration of a feature or features of a User Profile application service to another user, who is known as a feature administrator. A feature administrator can perform all administrative tasks that are related to the delegated feature or features, but a feature administrator cannot manage other features, service applications, or settings that are contained in Central Administration.

Reference: [Assign administration of User Profile service features (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721065%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: This is the comment for why its A) = "If you go to"Secure st srv" ==> administrators. You can select the "user or group" to grand admin rights only for this APP(context is tricky) ?

Comment: Benny, Documentation says that but I couldn't any way to create a "feature administrator" in SP 2010 environment, now in question its mentioning "Application" which can be a service application or a web application

Comment: @TimeToShine Strange how documentation can say one thing, and not be possible to implement. Is this alleged flaw confirmed by Microsoft?

Comment: @BennySkogberg I didn't said its not possible to implement it, I said I just couldn't find it, You can assign a single administrator to service applications who manage them, anyway I personally think this question is incomplete and I don't remember it coming up in 667 exam when I did it last month :)

Comment: Is the answer Configure User1 within the Secure Store Server as an administrator.? Since "If you go to"Secure st srv" ==> administrators. You can select the "user or group" to grand admin rights only for this APP(context is tricky)